# Existe algo similar find(de linux) en python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, debian

A ver es que quiero que mediante dos inputs introduzca el nombre de un fichero y un directorio. Y a partir de los nombres que yo les doy que me busque desde raíz hasta que encuentre dicho fichero o directorio. y que me devuelva la ruta ya que luego la voy a usar para moverme dentro del directorio con el os.chdir()

Comment: y que as intentado? que as investigado? te recomiendo pasar por la [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Pues mira lo unico que se me ha ocurrido es hacer un os.system(f"find -type d -name {Variable_input()}")

Comment: Hasta ahí bien me sale la ruta pero claro le paso la variable del input al os.chdir(Variable_input) y me sale siempre error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
import os

def list_files(filepath, _find):
   # guardaremos las coincidencias 
   paths = []
   # con os.walk() recorremos
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(filepath):
      #buscamos los archivos
      for file in files:
         # verificamos
         if file.lower() in _find.lower():
            # guardamos
            paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
   # retornamos
   return(paths)


files = list_files("C:\\Users\\Undefined\\Desktop","checkfile.py")

for x in files:
   print(x)
```

Comment: Ya lo hice y me funciono gracias

Comment: @Martinete si te funciono debes marcar la respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Gracias y sorry es que soy nuevo en todo esto jejeje